# How to break apart numeric vector with multiple values per entry in R

Tags: r, vector, numeric

I have run the "predict" function to get results from a logistical regression in R.  The results appear to be a numeric vector but each entry has two values.  I want to get this into a 2 column data frame and I'm not sure how. 
Here is some background on the data:

```
 head(fitted.results)
 1 2 3 4 5 6 
 0 0 0 0 0 0 
 class(fitted.results)
 [1] "numeric"
 tail(fitted.results)
 413 414 415 416 417 418 
  0  NA   1   0  NA  NA 
 length(fitted.results)
  418
 fitted.results[1]
 1 
 0
```

It appears to be of class numeric but with two entries per "row" although that is probably not the right term. So when I coerce to a dataframe, it only has one column.  I've tried using "matrix" with rows=418 but I get the same 1 column.  Such as:

```
d <- matrix(fitted.results, nrow = 418, byrow = TRUE)
```

I want to convert this to a 2 column dataframe so I can get a 2 column .csv file. I'm not sure how to separate out those values.

Comment: Can't tell since you didn't provide reproducible code, but it looks like a named vector? So try `cbind(names (fitted.results), fitted.results)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go with:

```
library(data.table)
x <- rnorm(15)
y <- x + rnorm(15)
pr<-predict(lm(y ~ x))
dt<-data.table(No=names(pr),pr)

       No         pr
    1:  1  2.3247191
    2:  2  0.5848808
    3:  3  2.3866168
    4:  4 -1.0213651
```

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @DougC just make sure to add as much information as possible in your initial request. Glad to help